# Mysql JOIN Select Query with Key in One field and Value in Another Field

Tags: mysql

I have to table I am trying to join

table user

```
id | name | age
----------------
 1 | Dave | 23
 2 | Dane | 65
 3 | Sam  | 15
```

table user_profile

```
user_id | profile_key  | profile_value
------------------------------------------------
  1     | prfle.about  | This is about Dave bio
  1     | prfle.cntry  | Germany
  2     | prfle.email  | dane@somewhere.com
  1     | prfle.email  | dave@somewhere.com
  3     | prfle.about  | This something about Sam
  2     | prfle.cntry  | Canada
```

I want to select the two tables as this

```
id | name | age  | prfle.about              | prfle.email        |  prfle.cntry
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | Dave | 23   | This is about Dave bio   | dave@somewhere.com | Germany
 2 | Dane | 65   |    null                  | dane@somewhere.com | Canada
 3 | Sam  | 15   | This something about Sam |  null              | null
```

This is my query

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.age, p.user_id, p.profile_key, p.profile_value
FROM user as u
LEFT JOIN user_profile as p
ON u.id = p.user_id
```

But when I execute it, I get something like a cartesian join.

I will be glad if anyone can help me

Comment: No. You get something like an outer join.

Answer (score 1):

If your `profile_key` values are limited then you can use the following approach to generate the pivot table as

```
select
u.*,
max(case when up.profile_key = 'prfle.about' then up.profile_value end ) as `prfle.about`,
max(case when up.profile_key = 'prfle.cntry' then up.profile_value end ) as `prfle.cntry`,
max(case when up.profile_key = 'prfle.email' then up.profile_value end ) as `prfle.email`
from user u
left join user_profile up on up.user_id = u.id
group by u.id
```